# wiring for a 4 wire AC motor

Tags: motor, h-bridge, wiring

I have a working garage door opener and I'd like to use its motor for building a edge sander (woodworking). The model number is the [Genie IMS1000](http://garagedoorsupplyco.com/Genie_AC_Screw_Drive_Schematic.html) and here is the [actual picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1waT7.jpg).

It has a single capacitor (labelled Cap in the picture below). I am only interested in making this turn one way at the fastest speed. Do you have any idea on how to wire this motor so I can use it?

On the capacitor, the yellow wire is connected to the yellow, and the same for orange..

[image: Imgur]

Comment: I am thinking that most likely this is not a good choice of motor. Get something from a washing machine or dryer. The garage door opener does not require high power, and is probably not designed to be run for extended periods. On the item labelled "cap" is there continuity from yellow to yellow and orange to orange? A capacitor is normally a two-terminal device. If you have four terminals, then it is not a simple capacitor.

Comment: One thing that would help, if it is still possible, is to reassemble the whole thing and make it go through the motion of opening and closing the door while you probe red/black or yellow/orange. Of course this could be dangerous (shock or electrocution hazard), so don't do it if you don't accept the risk.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks for the reply! Good point on the connectivity and the type of motor.  I do not have an ohm meter, will get one and report back.

Comment: @mkeith I looked at the wiring, and yes, there is continuity with yellow to yellow, and orange to orange. It is a capacitor with two terminals.

Answer (score 1):

I used a garage door motor with the gear drive assembly for a project. mkeith said it would probably overheat and he is right, the capacitor gets very hot if using it for more than a minute or 2. I have found a schematic on the internet if you can figure it out. Very strange wiring. And yes the capacitor is wired the way you show it. 
  Just as a thought, one side of the AC line is attached directly to the motor. Perhaps putting the other AC lead to one side of the capacitor will make it run one direction and switching to the other side of the capacitor for the other direction.
[image]

Comment: The purpose of the capacitor is for power factor correction, that is to reduce the phase shift between voltage and current.  Sanding can require a lot of torque for lengthy periods of time, depending on your use.  But garage door motors are designed to operate for only as long as it takes to lift the door.  Then they are allowed to cool off.   For woodworking you want a motor that has the mass to dissipate the heat and is sealed against dust.  Look for a low speed, high torque motor, the bigger the better.